# Mongo Cursor Exception: Timeout Waiting for Header Data

Tags: php, mongodb

My company recently added MongoDB to the databases that we use and things have been going mostly smoothly, but every once in a while we get an odd error. It is near impossible to duplicate, and has only happened four times in the last week of testing, but once we go live to production our clients will be using the site much more frequently than we were for testing. We are trying to solve the bug before it gets out of hand.

The error we get is: (line breaks added for readability)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 
'Failed to connect to: 10.0.1.114:27017: send_package: error reading from socket: 
Timed out waiting for header data' in 
/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/stage2/library/Shanty/Mongo/Connection/Group.php on line 134
```

We are using ShantyMongo in PHP and it is a remote connection. The error is really intermittent, and refreshing the page is enough to get it to go away. As a temporary solution, we have wrapped all of our mongo methods in a for...try/catch so that if a MongoException is thrown we retry the method up to two more times, the hope being that it will succeed one of the three attempts since the error is so unpredictable.

Comment: I would say this is a network problem, I would check the connection between you and the server

Comment: There was a loose connection with the NIC, replaced the cable and haven't seen the error again, but it was really intermittent to begin with